# Где getSharedPreferences() создает файл?

Tags: java, android

Я хочу в Preferences сохранить юзер ID. Во первых я не могу понять создается таблица или нет, так как нет никакого возвращаемого значения. Но даже если предположить, что таблица создалась с моим юзер ID, то где? Я на телефоне захожу в менеджер иду Android-->data-->МойПакет-->files и все... тут тупик, нет ни файлов с моими Preferences и вообще ничего... Может они скрыты?

```
SharedPreferences sPref = context.getSharedPreferences("Compare", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor editor = sPref.edit();
    editor.putString(USER_ID, userId);
    editor.apply();
```

Как найти этот файл и проверить на самом ли деле там, что то сохраняется?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Файл с `sharedPreference` создается в каталоге

`/data/data/имя_пакета_вашего_приложения/shared_prefs/`.

Чтобы туда посмотреть нужны root права на устройстве, и тогда можно будет до туда добраться через, например, установленный на телефоне Total Commander. 
Либо запускайте приложение на стандартном эмуляторе и через Android Monitor -> File Browser можно будет зайти в эту папку.

Comment: Добраться и так можно и даже увидеть, но не факт, что можно изменить или прочитать, вот тогда и нужны root.

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei без root прав у меня на телефоне в даже  ```/data``` не заходит.

Comment: у Вас нет, у меня без root заходит и даже файл видит, как похоже и у автора. Поэтому и коммент. Ответ хороший, я бы только добавил, как создается файл по default, если нет имени. И как в adb можно открыть с  run запросом и да действительно рут тогда не нужны.

Comment: Мне в этом случае помог 2-й вариант, я запустил приложение на эмуляторе и зашел через Android Monitor